# Y-axis exceeds the max value when height of highchart is decreased

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The yAxis values min and max are set to 0 and 100 with a tick interval of 20 by me.

But when the resolution is changed to a lower resolution or the chart is zoomed in,

I have observed that the height of the high hart decreases and the max value is set to 120 and tick interval to 40 on its own
Which is not the desired behavior can you please help me out how to avoid it?

How can i make sure the max is 100 with a tickinterval 20 in all chart heights and also in turn in lower resolution.

Thanks in advance

Note:- I believe the height is decreased because the xAxis labels rotate diagonally as the width is decreased (in lower resolution) and that occupies more space in the HTML div and causes the height of the chart to decrease.

[YAxis with expected behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9PS1.png)

[YAxis in lower resolution with decreased height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFQHx.png)

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/drgkt598/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: "column",
    height: 205,
    plotBackgroundColor: "#D3D3D3",
    width: 250,
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      pointPadding: 0
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    lineWidth: 2,
    type: 'category',
    lineColor: '#000',
    tickLength: 0
  },

  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    tickInterval: 10,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    plotLines: [{
      value: 70,
      color: 'black',
      dashStyle: "Solid",
      width: 4,
      zIndex: 5,
      label: {
        text: 39,
        align: "right",
        x: 2,
        y: -5,
        style: {
          color: 'black',
          fontWeight: "bold",
          fontSize: "18px",
        }
      }
    }],
  }, {
    linkedTo: 0,
    width: 60,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotBands: [{
        color: 'rgb(204,0,0)',
        from: 0,
        to: 30.99,
        zIndex: 1,
      },
      {
        color: 'rgb(226,113,113)',
        from: 31,
        to: 44.99,
        zIndex: 3,
      },
      {
        color: 'rgb(247,209,34)',
        from: 45,
        to: 54.99,
        zIndex: 3,
      },
      {
        color: 'rgb(136,207,136)',
        from: 55,
        to: 68.99,
        zIndex: 3,
      },
      {
        color: 'rgb(68,180,68)',
        from: 69,
        to: 87.99,
        zIndex: 3,
      },
      {
        color: 'rgb(0,153,0)',
        from: 88,
        to: 100,
        zIndex: 3,
      }
    ]
  }],
  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      color: "white",
      verticalAlign: "bottom",
      crop: false,
      style: {
        fontWeight: "Normal"
      }
    },
    data: [{
      y: 85,
      name: 'A',
      color: 'red',
      dataLabels: {
        formatter() {
          return '<span style="font-size:11px;">A</span>';
        },
        y: -20
      }
    }, {
      y: 72,
      name: 'B',
      color: 'green',
      dataLabels: {
        formatter() {
          return '<span style="font-size:11px;">B</span>';
        },
        y: -15
      }
    }, {
      y: 83,
      name: 'C',
      color: 'blue',
      dataLabels: {
        formatter() {
          return '<span style="font-size:11px;">C</span>';
        },
        y: -15
      }
    }],
    showInLegend: false
  }]

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you have noted - there is not enough space to render 5 labels for some smaller dimensions, so implemented logic tries to calculate other timestamps, which will fit, like `[0, 40, 80, 120]`.

I think that you can control it by using the responsive options and set the `tickInterval` to another value like 50.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zupbe174/

```
  responsive: {
    rules: [{
      condition: {
        maxHeight: 120
      },
      chartOptions: {
        yAxis: [{
          tickInterval: 50
        }, {

        }]
      }
    }]
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules.condition

Comment: Hi @Sebastian thanks for the response, is there any other way to handle this other than decreasing the number of labels as I need to have tick-interval as 20 and six labels.

Comment: @Nagachandra another solution which came to my mind is changing the `labels.fontSize`, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9uta70pj/

Comment: Hi @Sebastian thanks for the solution this was helpful.